# JSP - Update texarea on button click

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am building a JSP webapp using Tomcat and Maven.
I want to update the value of a textarea in my jsp page when a button on that same jsp page is clicked.

In my XMLProcessor class I have a function called returnNextMessage() which returns a string of data.

my jsp:

```
<%@ page import="efidbg.XMLProcessor"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="base" class="">

    <!-- Textbox that i want to fill using java function. -->
    <div id="u1" class="ax_default text_area">
      <textarea id="u1_input"></textarea>
    </div>

<!-- Button when clicked call returnNextMessage() function -->
    <div id="u9" class="ax_default primary_button">
  <form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
    <input
      type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to implement it using a servlet called MyServlet but that seems to redirect me to a new page which makes me think that using a servlet is not the correct way to achieve this.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Value = XMLProcessor.returnNextMessage();
    request.setAttribute("u1_input", Value);
}
```

When I press the submit button I just get redirected to Localhost/MyServlet which gives me an empty page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JSP file like below:

```html
<%@ page import="efidbg.XMLProcessor"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="base" class="">
<!-- Button when clicked call returnNextMessage() function -->
    <div id="u9" class="ax_default primary_button">
  <form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
    <!-- Textbox that i want to fill using java function. -->
    <div id="u1" class="ax_default text_area">
      <textarea id="u1_input">${u1_input}</textarea>
    </div>
    <input
      type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And add the code in your java method after you set the attribute.

`request.getRequestDispatcher("/xxx.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Comment: move `<form action="MyServlet" method="POST">` to above textarea div

Comment: When i click the button it redirects the page to localhost/myservlet and displays a nullpointer because it cant find the textbox anymore.

Comment: Is it the value is a null pointer? More debug information maybe helpful.

Comment: Yeah my value was null, my bad. However, now it just opens an empty servlet instead of setting a value in my textbox.

Comment: @The Donger maybe a request dispatch to jsp is needed

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
<textarea id="u1_input" value="${u1_input}"></textarea>
```

jsp engine will replace ${u1_input} with his value.